# Shearlets: Why are parabolic scaling matrices $A_a := \text{diag}(a, \sqrt{a})$ called parabolic

Tags: functional-analysis, machine-learning, wavelets

For [continuous shearlet systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shearlet#Continuous_shearlet_systems) the parabolic scaling matrices $$A_a := \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{a}\end{pmatrix}, \quad a > 0$$
are very important.
Why are they called parabolic?

I thought of making a quadratic form from the matrix, i.e. $Q(x,y) := (x,y) \cdot A \cdot (x,y)^T$. This gives
$$
Q(x,y)
= ax^2 + \sqrt{a}x y,
$$
which has discriminant $b^2 - 4ac = - 4 a^{\frac{3}{2}} < 0$, so we should be calling it hyperbolic, right?

Comment: "Sherbet" is a frozen dessert :-).  You might want to contemplate the geometric meaning of the image of the map $a\to A_a$ where the matrix $A_a$ is considered a point in $\mathbb{R}^4.$  As a quadratic form, $Q$ has discriminant $a^{3/2}:$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Quadratic_forms. Finally, quadratic forms with positive discriminant are termed *elliptic,* not hyperbolic.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for spotting the autocorrect. Reading up on your provided link I noticed I must have confused quadratic forms and conic sections, since for conic sections it says "if the discriminant [b^2 - 4ac] is zero, the curve is a parabola [...]. If the discriminant is positive, the curve is a hyperbola [...]".

Comment: Concerning which point(s)? Anent the first, the image of the map $a\to A_a$ is half of a parabola. This becomes clear when you adopt a basis $e_{11}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},e_{12}=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},e_{21}=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},e_{22}=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$ for then the image is the set $\{ye_{11}+xe_{22}\mid y=x^2,x\gt 0\}.$

Comment: @whuber Oh now I see thank you very much. Feel free to post this as an answer, I will accept it.